# Reactor: Backpressure and buffering without overflow

Tags: spring, project-reactor

I can't seem to get an unbounded source to work with `bufferTimeout` without falling into unlimited demand. My source has a lot of data, but I can selectively pull from it, so there is no need to buffer a lot of data in memory if it isn't requested. However, I cannot figure out how to get reactor to both 1. Not request unlimited demand. 2. Not overflow when the source is a bit slow to respond.

Here is a JUnit test case:

```
  @Test
    void bufferAllowsRequested() throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService workers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        AtomicBoolean down = new AtomicBoolean();

        Flux.generate(sink -> {
            produceRequestedTo(down, sink);
        }).concatMap(Flux::fromIterable).bufferTimeout(400, Duration.ofMillis(200))
                .doOnError(t -> {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    down.set(true);
                })
                .publishOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(workers), 4)
                .subscribe(this::processBuffer);

        Thread.sleep(3500);

        workers.shutdownNow();

        assertFalse(down.get());
    }

    private void processBuffer(List<Object> buf) {
        System.out.println("Received " + buf.size());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(400);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void produceRequestedTo(AtomicBoolean down, SynchronousSink<Object> sink) {
        Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1000));
        try {
            sink.next(IntStream.range(0, 500).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            down.set(true);
        }
    }
```

I've tried both Flux.create and Flux.generate, but both seem to suffer from this problem. I don't understand how this isn't a common use case.

I filed an issue here: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1557

Comment: _"Not overflow when the source is a bit slow to respond"_ In your case the subscriber is too slow. _"Not request unlimited demand"_ you need to implement your own subscriber.

Comment: Oliver, Can you explain this? Link, example, anything? Your hint is vague and unsupported.

Comment: Explain what? How to implement a subscriber?